# C++ Universal Character Set to code and vise versa

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a simple C++ string encrypter/decrypter

The algorithm passes for every character in the input, takes the unicode value, then passes for every character in the key and add the first unicode value with the key character unicode value.

To decrypt it decreases the first unicode value with the key character unicode value.

This is a piece of code:

```
std::string encrypt(std::string Input, std::string Key) {
    std::string result = "";
    int text_size = Input.size();
    int key_size = Key.size();

    for (int t_i = 0; t_i < text_size; t_i++) {
        int result_char = (int)Input.at(t_i);
        for (int k_i = 0; k_i < key_size; k_i++) {
            result_char += (int)Key.at(k_i);
        }
        result += char(result_char);
    }
    return result;
}

std::string decrypt(std::string Input, std::string Key) {
    std::string result = "";
    int text_size = Input.size();
    int key_size = Key.size();

    for (int t_i = 0; t_i < text_size; t_i++) {
        int result_char = (int)Input.at(t_i);
        for (int k_i = 0; k_i < key_size; k_i++) {
            result_char -= (int)Key.at(k_i);
        }
        result += char(result_char);
    }
    return result;
}
```

But when I use out-range ASCII characters like an emoji, it completely breaks like this:

```
String to encrypt:  This is an test, ÆÆÆ
String encrypted:  ����    � ǻ^!^!^!
String decrypted:  T$"hisT$"isT$"T$"nT$"test, ÆÆÆ
```

Please note: The encrypted string is acceptable that appear completely broken, as it's encrypted and the terminal isn't configured to print that characters. But the decrypted string need to be the same as the original string.

I need an explanation and a REAL solution on how to resolve this.

I've already searched every kind of solution but none of then I could use.

**EDIT:**

The solution from @Remy Lebau that worked to me:

```
std::u16string encrypt(std::u16string Input, std::u16string Key) {
    std::u16string result;
    int text_size = Input.size();
    int key_size = Key.size();

    for (int t_i = 0; t_i < text_size; t_i++) {
        int result_char = Input[t_i];
        for (int k_i = 0; k_i < key_size; k_i++) {
            result_char += Key[k_i];
        }
        result += (unsigned char)result_char;
    }
    return result;
}

std::u16string decrypt(std::u16string Input, std::u16string Key) {
    std::u16string result;
    int text_size = Input.size();
    int key_size = Key.size();

    for (int t_i = 0; t_i < text_size; t_i++) {
        int result_char = Input[t_i];
        for (int k_i = 0; k_i < key_size; k_i++) {
            result_char -= Key[k_i];
        }
        result += (unsigned char)result_char;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Result:

```
String to encrypt:  This is an test, ÆÆÆ
String encrypted:  ï»»ü    » Ç»aaa
String decrypted:  This is an test, ÆÆÆ
```

I used std::u16string to be able to use universal character set and (unsigned char) casting to convert from codepoint to character.

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: There is no Unicode handling in this code at all. In fact, it doesn't really care about characters at all, it is really just operating on bytes instead. But you are not taking into account that `char` can be either `signed` or `unsigned` depending on the compiler implementation. Consider casting the `char` values to `unsigned int` before you perform arithmetic operations on them. Also, you should be using `size_t` instead of `int` for your loop counters, and there is no need to use `std::string::at()` since your loops do not go out of bounds, use `std::string::operator[]` instead.

Comment: And it should really be easy to figure out the problem by using a debugger, a text of 1 or 2 characters and a key of the same length. Even better, do the computation on paper first and then trace the code and you will see exactly were the problem is.

Comment: Only the sum of the characters in the key matters. A key of `"password"` is equivalent to `"asdowpsr"`. There are only 256 unique keys (assuming characters are in an 8-bit byte). Were you trying to make a [Vigenère cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau So where exactly I need to cast the unsigned int?

Comment: What you have here is basically a [Caesar cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher).

Comment: @Kerndog73 In the real code, I multiply the unicode value of the key character by the key character position (k_i), so the right key is always "password", discarding any "anagram" of the key.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you need to cast to `unsigned char`, since if char is signed then it'll still be sign-extended to unsigned int

Comment: What do you mean by "unicode value"? Because here you're just dealing with bytes. Is this meant to deal with unicode codepoints?

Comment: @Kerndog73 Yes, my code is an implementation of the Caesar Cipher, but the string is shifted by a second string. In the real code, I make some modifications on how each letter is shifted so there isn't an pattern. The attacker would need to make an brute force to discover the key. All of that in theory

Comment: If the plaintext string is meant to be shifted by the key string, then you're trying to implement a Vigenère cipher but as I've already said, the code in the question is a Caesar cipher.

Comment: @Kerndog73 So, when I say the "unicode value" I'm trying to say a ASCII value, but the ASCII table only covers 128 characters (with printing and non-printing characters). The unicode table takes every character possible, consenquently, when I need to return any character code value, it returns properly.

Comment: I just want to know if there's a way to return ANY character code value in int, to be able to shift it and "de-shift" later. I made the program variation in Javascript (I used charCodeAt to take the character code value and String.fromCharCode to convert to character) and it worked without problems

Comment: That's because JavaScript uses UTF-16 strings

Comment: But none of this should really matter, just as long as you handle you overflow and underflow correctly. Just assume that the strings are sequences of bytes and make no assumptions beyond that. It will be much easier than trying to turn UTF-8 into a sequence of unicode codepoints, and dealing with those, and then converting back to UTF-8.

Comment: The first comment has the solution to your problem